# Teams app Azure Devops Connector for Azure devops server (self hosted)

Tags: azure-devops, tfs

I am trying to add the Azure Devops Server app connector (webhook) on Teams that will connect to the self hosted Azure Devops (TFS) 2022, more like a service connection, but  when I click on the setup I am not given the option to be able to add the URL for the self hosted server. All I can see is the the ones online/service organization. I know the boards, pipeline and other service specific apps won't work on the self hosted server on Teams app integration but the Azure Devops Server app connectors according to the documentation should work for the self hosted server. Has anyone come across similar issue? any advice that can be followed? Any input would be very helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When accessing the Azure Devops apps on teams it expects teams and azure devops server to be on the same domain. Since we have them on different ones it did not recognize the organization.

I got around it by installing a Webhook application on teams and creating the service connection that posts to teams though this webhook.